# What is "subordination" with respect to stochastic processes?

Tags: stochastic-processes, terminology

I'm building a model for a panel of counts, $\{n_{kt}\}_{k,t}$.

As I read about regression methods for count models and the stochastic processes behind them, the concept of one random variable being "subordinated" to another often comes up (for example in [Kozubowski and Podgorski, 2009](http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~pms/files/29.1/Article/29.1.3.pdf)). What does this mean? In particular, how does one read notation like $X_U$?

Comment: While my interest is in statistical modeling, this concept hasn't come up on stats.SE, so I think this is the best place for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subordinator is a concept that applies to Lévy processes, where it is used as a stochastic time change which is itself an almost surely increasing Lévy process.

The thing is that the resulting process is still itself a Lévy process which is why it attracts interest. You can have a look at this [paper](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/wp/2005/wp05174.pdf). In general, every book on Lévy processes and stochastic calculus treats the subject, for example the book by Applebaum must have a section on this.